# Open tag arrows showing up in browser but don't exist in my code

Tags: html, html-table, console

This is a hard one to explain, but I have 3 phantom arrows (<<<) appearing in the browser, but no stray arrows in my HTML.

When I inspect the element, the arrows are a child of my 'bookshelf-wrapper' container.

Where are these arrows coming from and how can I get rid of them?

Screenshot attached as gives clearer indication than code.

[image: Phantom arrows:]

Side note - I realise it's 'Picture' not 'Portrait'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check html for multiple openings like '<<'. As far as I can see from the image 1 '<' is comming from  with the input#delete.

in image I can see:

```
<<td class="cell"><input type="checkbox" id="delete"></td>
```

should be without extra '<':

```
<td class="cell"><input type="checkbox" id="delete"></td>
```

If it doesn't solves your problem, please provide more code and I'll update my answer

Comment: Oh my gosh I feel so dumb now! I scoured the code for arrows multiple times, must've kept missing them. Thanks for pointing them out!

Comment: to prevent these kind of mistakes TSlint, plugins in ide is a very good thing to have, because all these mistakes would be higlinten/alerted :)

Comment: Thanks! I have ESLint but I don’t think I’ve installed it properly, so I’ll check it out :)